# Best way to iterate throught returned models

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-artisan, laravel-query-builder

I have a table named Drug basically when a drug is inserted it takes is_accepted 0 by default so it needs to be accepted by an administrator.
All the drugs are shown on the website if their `is_accepted` value is 1

I have created a command `DeleteunacceptedDrugs` that will run every 12 hours.

This command will get all the drugs that their value `is_accepted` is 0 and check their waiting time (how long that they are in wait state)

```
public function handle()
    {
        $drugs =  Drug::where('is_accepted',0)->get();

        for($i=0;$i<count($drugs);$i++){
            if($drugs[$i]->getDuration() >= 12){
                $drugs[$i]->delete();
            }
        }

    }
```

This code works fine deletes all the drugs that their waiting time (`current_date - created_at`) is higher than 12 but the code looks ugly to me is there a way for a better iteration approach through drugs array

If you need it

```
 public function getDuration(){
    
            $start = Carbon::parse($this->created_at);
            $end = now();
            $hours = $end->diffInHours($start);
            return $hours;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the diff directly in the query:

```php
Drug::where('is_accepted',0)->whereRaw('HOUR(TIMEDIFF(created_at, NOW())) > 11')->delete();
```